# Using CURLOPT_CAINFO with updated CA bundle causes certificate verify failed

Tags: php, curl

I use cURL to verify PayPal transactions in a WordPress plugin. Recently I started receiving bug reports about user not being able to complete the purchase process because the transaction couldn't be verified. I tracked down the error to:

```
SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details: 
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
```

I found a lot of questions here in StackOverflow related to the same problem, most of them said the solution was to provide a bundle of CA using `CURLOPT_CAINFO` cURL's option. I downloaded and currently ship with the plugin the most recent version (converted on Jun 28, 2012) of http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem. That solved most of the issues I had received.

The problem now, is that I just received another report of failed payments and the error was the same: `SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK.`. The interesting part is that now the solution was to **remove** the `CURLOPT_CAINFO` option. I'm wondering if there is in explanation for this. I thought using an updated CA bundle, such as the one I downloaded, was a general solution but it appears to be otherwise.

What would be a general solution for this kind of problem? and what could explain that using the updated CA bundle causes SSL certificate problems, instead of fixing them?.

This is the cURL configuartion:

```
<?php
    $ch = curl_init("https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, '/path/to/cacert.pem');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $content);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
?>
```

**UPDATE**:
The certificate for www.paypal.com is signed by VeriSign. The Certificate Hierarchy (as shown in Firefox) is:

- VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5
- VeriSign Class 3 Extended Validation SSL CA
- www.paypal.com

I can confirm the certificate for *VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5* is included in the version I'm using of http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: (Are you still having this problem?) Just to narrow the inquiry: Are you connecting to PayPal from the same host for every request? Meaning, the same source code, from the same machine, will occasionally throw this error?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. The code above is part of a WordPress plugin. I was seeing different results with the same source code, but different machines. Some users reported problems when the custom certificate bundle was used, and others reported problems when the default bundle was used. My solution was to support both scenarios: try with the custom bundle and repeat the request without it, in case of error.

Comment: Interesting problem. The solution you describe seems like your best bet. Without tracking each users php + curl version it'd be hard to isolate the cause: is it permissions problem, a legacy API, a historical php/curl bug, a misconfigured host? Too many factors. Suffice to say I think preferring a custom up to date CA bundle is a good practice and should be dependable for well configured modern php environments.

Answer (score 11):

If you are having this problem, please, do **not** disable peer and host verification as someone has suggested.

This will leave your communications open to potential man-in-the-middle attacks, defeating the purpose of using SSL in the first place.

One potential explanation for this issue is that setting your `CURLOPT_CAINFO` (especially to an incorrect certificate path - I would double-double check this) overrode the default path on your server.

Once you removed the setting, it returned to its default (which can be set in PHP).

Another thing to keep in mind is that `CURLOPT_CAINFO` is an absolute path.

Comment: Thank you @Tim_K. I'm still using peer and host verification.

Back then I was working on a WordPress plugin and there were only a few hosts that were showing SSL problems **after** I introduced the custom certificate bundle. I never figured the reason; since most of the other hosts were just working. I ended up doing the requests using the custom certificate bundle and falling back to use the default one (removing the `CURLOPT_CAINFO` setting) if problems appeared.

Answer (score 3):

see this url

http://davidwalsh.name/php-ssl-curl-error

**or try it**

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,'https://thirdparty.com/token.php'); //not the actual site
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,60);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,'customer_id='.$cid.'&password='.$pass);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,true); 
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CAINFO,'mozilla.pem'); /* fixed! */
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if(empty($result)) { /* error: nothing returned */ } else { /* success! */ }
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Tx @AbidHussain, I believe mozzila.pem is the same file I'm using with a different name. Using that bundle fixed the issue in most of the cases I have seen, but it also breaks things for other users. Which is what I'm trying to understand now.