# cURL connection to a https page

Tags: php, curl, ssl, https

So I have this code :

```
$url = "https://..."; //a valid url, showing without errors a correct XML

$handle = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);

/* to which i added the following */
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_CAPATH, "http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem");
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, TRUE);

$result = curl_exec($handle);
$resultXml = new SimpleXMLElement($result); //Line 47

/* tests */
var_dump($handle); echo "<br/><br/>"; //resource(11) of type (curl) 
var_dump($url);    echo "<br/><br/>"; //string(149) "https://..." (exactly $url)
var_dump($result); echo "<br/><br/>"; //bool(false)
```

That generates this error :

```
Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'String could not be parsed as XML' [...] on line 47
Stack trace:
#0 C:\yy.php(47): SimpleXMLElement->__construct('')
#1 C:\xx.php(23): Integrator->Integrator('numbers', Object(Database))
#2 {main}
thrown [...] on line 47
```

What var_dump() returns is in comments.

Using it, we can see that $result is empty; this is the main issue !

I first thought that the problem was from the https connection to the page, so I've added the 3 lines in the middle; the problem remains the same.

Now I'm wondering if the fact that my SSL certificate (from Gandi SAS) isn't clearly included in http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem is the problem. 
If so, how do I tell CURLOPT_CAPATH to get my certificate?

Is the error elsewhere ?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use CURLOPT_CAINFO to specify the certificate file.

```
CURLOPT_CAINFO - The name of a file holding one or more certificates to
verify the peer with. This only makes sense when used in combination with
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER.
```

This needs to be an absolute path to the file.

Once you fix the ssl issue, you should get the data in your curl response.

Comment: I have tryed with CURLOPT_CAINFO, but is the order important? So far, nothing new with errors.

Comment: Looks like we have a related topic here which might be of use.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12305157/using-curlopt-cainfo-with-updated-ca-bundle-causes-certificate-verify-failed